# Поведение Entity и приложения при использовании атрибутов валидации

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем привет. Возникла очень странная проблема. Есть код модели с закоментированными атрибутами

```
public class Class1
    {
        //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
    class DataSource : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Class1> datas { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот метода действия который работает с `Class1` и Entity

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MvcApplication1.Models.Class1 c)
        {
            d.datas.Add(c);
            d.SaveChanges();
            return View(d.datas);
        }
```

И кусок вью, который это все обрабатывает. Вьюха типизирована как `@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Class1>` в качестве модели она принимает `d.datas` - то есть БД.

```
@if(Model != null)
        { 
        foreach(Class1 c in Model)
        {
            @c.Name<br />
            @c.Message<br />
            <hr />
        }
        }
```

Вопрос состоит в том, что когда атрибуты валидации закомментированы, то все работает прекрасно. То есть в программе есть два поля `Name` и `Message` вводят туда что-то и введенные данные по нажатии кнопки типа POST идут в БД и сразу выводятся. Но если валидацию раскоментировать, то при нажатии кнопки для POST выводится вот такая вот ошибка
`The model backing the 'DataSource' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).` Несмотря на то, что все поля с атрибутом Required заполнены. Это появилось при моем переходе со студии 2012 в 2013. Решается эта проблема прописыванием в методе `Application_Start()` такой вот строчки `Database.SetInitializer<MvcApplication1.Models.DataSource>(null);` Что это все значит не могу понят, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: изменилась структура бд. сделайть миграцию и будет счастье

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто. Когда вы добавили атрибуты `Required` - соответствующие им колонки в схеме БД перестали считаться NULLABLE (то есть были NULL, а стали NOT NULL). Используемая схема БД изменилась - значит БД надо обновить.

Answer (score 1):

> The model backing the 'DataSource' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)

в данном сообщении говорится приблизительно следующее: контекст изменился с момента создания базы данных. Рассмотрите возможность использования миграции для обновления БД. [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/data/jj591621)